# Set Github Actions variables from Pipeline

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to change the GitHub actions variable value which is created through the Github UI in `settings -> secrets & variables -> variables` when my pipeline finishes.

Note that I want to change the persisted value, not a value or env variable inside the workflow.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be updated. You can use curl with relevant values in your GitHub action workflow.

```
curl -L \
  -X PATCH \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/variables/NAME \
  -d '{"name":"USERNAME","value":"octocat"}'
```

Refer to official doc - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/variables?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-repository-variable

Comment: Thanks, completely skipped APIs and was blindly thinking about existing actions...